# Angular: Combining Observables in series and parallel

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, angular5

I have problems showing my data from JSON. I do have one main JSON which looks like this:

```
"providers": [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "name1",
    "data": "http://localhost:3001/name1"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "name2",
    "data": "http://localhost:3001/name2"
  }
]
```

the url in the data field needs to be called to get another JSON file (detail-info) which have more information about the specific element.

I created now a service which should load all the data comming from the detail-info and safe it inside the providers.data. I am now totally confused about the response I got. Can someone clarify or explain what I am doing wrong at this side? Here are the code fragments:

```
export interface Provider {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  data: any;
}

export interface Providers {
  providers: Provider[];
}
```

// service.ts:

```
getListelements() {

        return this.http.get<Providers>(this.url)
          .map((res) => res)
          .map((providers) => {
            if (providers.providers.length > 0) {

              return Observable.forkJoin(
                providers.providers
                  .map((provider: Provider) => {
                  return this.http.get(provider.data)
                    .map((res) => {
                      providers.providers.data = this.mapElement(res);
                      return providers;
                  });
                })
              );
            }
            return Observable.of(providers);
          })
          .share();
      }
```

// component.ts

```
getListelements(): void {
    this.listelementService.getListelements().subscribe(
      data => { this.data = data;},
      err => this.messageService.add(err)
 });
  }
```

with `.flatMap` or `.concatMap` my Output returns wrongly

```
"providers": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "name1",
        "data": "http://localhost:3001/name1"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "name2",
        "data": "http://localhost:3001/name2"
      },
      "data": {"id":"1", "name":"name1", "furtherinfo":"lorem ipsum"}
    ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using just `map()` whose projection function returns an Observable (`Observable.forkJoin`) but you want to subscribe to this Observable and get its result not pass the Observable further.

So instead of `map()` you should use `concatMap()` or `mergeMap()` (`switchMap` will works as well in this case).

```
return this.http.get<Providers>(this.url)
  .map((res) => res)
  .concatMap((providers) => {
    return Observable.forkJoin(...) ;
  });
```

Edit:

```
const observables = providers.providers
  .map((provider: Provider) => this.http.get(provider.data)
    .map(response => {
      provider.data = this.mapElement(response);
      return provider;
    })
  );

return Observable.forkJoin(observables)
```

Comment: right! But now my Output is not mapped correctly: 
"providers": [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "name1",
    "data": "http://localhost:3001/name1"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "name2",
    "data": "http://localhost:3001/name2"
  },
"data": {id:'id1', nam:'"name1",imgurl:'abc.png'}
]
Instead I would like to overwrite the data-field

Comment: I don't know what your data looks like but I think this part `.map((res) => { providers.providers.data = this.mapElement(res); return providers; });` Where you update something inside `providers` and then return it is suspicious because this is called for every `this.http.get` response and it looks like it's overriding itself repeatedly.

Comment: ok I understand... so is there any best case to solve such a data handling of several jsons? Is it good to create a separate mapper object?

Comment: See my update, I think this should do it but since I can't test it myself I'm mostly just guessing.